# jqGrid for large no of columns

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json, jqgrid

I have large no of columns in my data source to be loaded into the `jqGrid`. As we need to specify col Names and col Model, it will be very time consuming for me to write all the col Names and col Model each column. It is like I have 80 columns in the datatable and 10 tables in the database.
Is there any way to skip the column definition like in ASP.NET Grid-View control where we just bind it with data source and all the columns are populated same as in the database.

```
JQuery("JQGrid").jqGrid({
    url:'JQGridHandler.ashx',
    datatype:'json',
    colNames:[], // here something to skip and load all columns from the file
    colModel:[],
    mtype:'POST',
    loadonce:true,
    viewrecords:true,
    caption:"Database Table"
});
```

Comment: If you don't specify anything for the `colModel` or `colNames` does it render any by default?  You might also try different plugins, such as DataTables, which can just be applied to any HTML table and use its existing columns by default.

Comment: The code which you posted contains almost anything. Even the posted text contains a lot of errors: `JQuery` instead of `jQuery`, `dattype` instead of `datatype`, `coModel` (or `col Model`) instead of `colModel`, `mType` instead of `mtype`,... I really want to answer you: the answer on your question in here "...", but I skipped details to save the place.

Comment: To be serious: ASP.NET code is **server based code** it can have access to the database model, but jqGrid is pure open source **JavaScript** library (jQuery plugin). So it can't have any direct access to model/data for automatic binding. You have to write or generate `colModel` based on the information about your grid. Alternatively you can use *commercial product* created based on jqGrid (like from http://www.trirand.net/) which help you in the case. You should still consider whether the user really will read (need) all 80 columns and many rows of data.

Comment: @David It is displaying nothing if I am specifying blank in the colNames and colModel. Much like I need to try Datatable. Thanks